# installing sf package with libraries in non-standard locations

Tags: r, linux, gdal, rgdal, r-sf

The required libraries are in non-standard locations and I can install rgdal by the command below:

```r
install.packages('rgdal', type = "source", 
configure.args=c('--with-gdal-config=/home/programs/anaconda3/bin/gdal-config',
'--with-proj-include=/home/programs/anaconda3/include',
'--with-proj-lib=/home/programs/anaconda3/lib'))
```

But I can't install `sf` package. It keeps saying `configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.`. The installation code and output is below. Do you have any hint?

```r
install.packages('sf', type = "source", 
configure.args='--with-gdal-config=/home/programs/anaconda3/bin/gdal-config --with-geos-config=/home/programs/anaconda3/bin/geos-config --with-proj-include=/home/programs/anaconda3/include/ --with-proj-lib=/home/programs/anaconda3/lib/')
```

```
* installing *source* package ‘sf’ ...
** package ‘sf’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: CC: gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
configure: CXX: g++ -m64 -std=gnu++11
configure: gdal-config set to /home/programs/anaconda3/bin/gdal-config
checking gdal-config exists... yes
checking gdal-config executable... yes
checking gdal-config usability... yes
configure: GDAL: 2.4.1
checking GDAL version >= 2.0.0... yes
checking for gcc... gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking gdal.h usability... yes
checking gdal.h presence... yes
checking for gdal.h... yes
checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... yes
checking GDAL: /home/programs/anaconda3/share/gdal/pcs.csv readable... yes
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available for linking:... yes
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available fur running:... yes
checking proj_api.h usability... no
checking proj_api.h presence... no
checking for proj_api.h... no
configure: error: proj_api.h not found in standard or given locations.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘sf’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/sf’
```

R set-up info:

```
platform       x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          5.2
year           2018
month          12
day            20
svn rev        75870
language       R
version.string R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
nickname       Eggshell Igloo
```

Comment: You should also set the following `LDFLAGS`: `-L/home/programs/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-R,/home/programs/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags` (assuming they are passed through the compiler).

Comment: I just tried the command `sudo LDFLAGS="-L/home/programs/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-R,/home/programs/anaconda3/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags" R CMD INSTALL sf_0.7-3.tar.gz --configure-args='--with-gdal-config=/home/programs/anaconda3/bin/gdal-config --with-geos-config=/home/programs/anaconda3/bin/geos-config --with-proj-include=/home/programs/anaconda3/include --with-proj-lib=/home/programs/anaconda3/lib'` but it still complains, same `proj_api.h` not found error.

Comment: I had a similar problem with the lwgeom package. Found this [github comment](https://github.com/r-spatial/lwgeom/issues/28#issuecomment-478325216) that solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to all who comments; this issue was originated from CentOS's `sudo` settings. OS was set up that user environment variables will not be available in `sudo` environment, so setting an environment variable in user `.bashrc` file wouldn't solve the issue. Hence, to install `sf` package, I have to start `R` with `sudo` and with correct environment variables in command line, then install `sf` package in `R`.

First, run R with required environment variables,

```
sudo PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/programs/anaconda3/lib/pkgconfig/" LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/programs/anaconda3/lib" R
```

Second, install `sf`.

```
remotes::install_github("r-spatial/sf", configure.args = "--with-gdal-config=/home/programs/anaconda3/bin/gdal-config --with-geos-config=/home/programs/anaconda3/bin/geos-config --with-proj-include=/home/programs/anaconda3/include/ --with-proj-lib=/home/programs/anaconda3/lib/")
```

Again, excuse me for spending your time, I hope this post helps someone.

See: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/335#issuecomment-484985276